# All documents with a field in result which states if each query exists in the doc

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query elasticsearch to fetch all the documents in index with extra information. Example below:
Suppose I have multiple queries having one/multiple terms like "A B C", "D", "F G", and I want all the documents in the index with information for each query stating whether the query(exact match) exists in the document.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you exemplify? Maybe  mention what you tried already.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Currently I am using Scroll and Scan to iterate over all the documents in the index and checking if some n-grams are present in the doc and save those values in a file for each doc. I was wondering if there is some other way? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please, share a sample query of what you have now, because it's confusing. You say scan&scroll - yes, this is recommended if you want to retrieve all documents. But "multiple queries having one/multiple terms like "A B C", "D", "F G", and I want all the documents in the index with information for each query stating whether the query(exact match) exists in the document" is really confusing...

Comment: @AndreiStefan  
I don't have have a query for this. I am using elasticsearch API for JAVA. Explaining this: "multiple queries having one/multiple terms like "A B C", "D", "F G", and I want all the documents in the index with information for each query stating whether the query(exact match) exists in the document" "A B C", "D", "F G" are 3 n-grams that I want to use for quering but I need all the documents from elasticsearch with some flag/count which indicates the presence of these n-grams. Example, "A B C" : true, "D" : true, "F G": false, if "A B C" and "D" are present in a doc.

Comment: Maybe you could boost or give a fixed score for each of the terms that match and add these fixed scores. In the end, if the document matched at least one of the terms you will get a score. And from that score, based on the uniqueness of the custom fixed scores you could tell which matched. For example: for "A B C" you have a fixed score of 1000, for "D" you have a fixed score of 10, for "F G" you have 1. If the document gives you a total score of 1001 you will know that ABC and FG matched. And so on...